# C#: Populate DataTable from SqlDataReader with the ability to interrupt?

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, datatable

I would like to fill a `DataTable` object via a `SqlDataReader` and have the ability to interrupt the operation (eg via the u/i in the case a user wants to cancel a long running query).

Unfortunately, I don't see any overload of `DataTable.Load()` that takes a `CancellationToken`.

Is there a clean way to achieve this?

(My only thought is use a thread and see if `Thread.Interrupt()` does the trick and if not then `Thread.Abort()` but that seems pretty unfriendly).

Comment: it takes miliseconds to fill thousands of rows. Rather than this, you can put condition in query itself.

Comment: @DheerajRoy can you explain?  i've got queries that take a LONG time to return anything including metadata.  how do i put the "condition in the query"?

Comment: I think you should look into the DataTable RowChanged via the SqlDataAdapter.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Task and a cancellation token.  Of course, you will have to fill the DataTable manually instead of using the Load method.

```
private void FillTable(CancellationToken token)
{
    var reader = new SqlDataReader();
    var dt = CreateDataTable();
    while(reader.Read() && !token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        // fill row from reader....
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

You would use this method like this :

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FillTable(tokenSource.Token), tokenSource.Token);
```

Then you can cancel the operation :

```
tokenSource.Cancel();
```

Comment: fleshing it out, I guess I would want `reader.ReadAsync()` in my case.  how do I implement `CreateDataTable()` when I want the metadata to be based on the query results?  Thanks!

Comment: I guess you can do something like this `DataTable dt = reader.GetSchemaTable();` where reader is the SqlDataReader.

Comment: ... and back to blocking on slow query :-(?  I've got some doozies that may take minutes to return metadata (don't ask).

Comment: Well you need your query to return something to get the schema, there's no way around this.  May be you should work on optimizing your queries.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a generic front end that works similar to Query Analyzer in that it should be able to interrupt and cancel a running query regardless of the characteristics of the query.  Ideally, MS would support a CancellationToken on the `Load` call, but no such luck :-(.

Comment: You should try @William Xifaras suggestion, i think it will do what you want to achieve..

Answer (score 0):

Coupled with a SqlDataAdapter, you can handle the DataTable RowChanged event and either throw an exception or close the data adapter's connection which causes an InvalidOperationException to be thrown.

Take a look at the following example ([source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ad4f5811-a08d-4342-bcf1-368ceac834fc/is-there-any-way-to-cancel-a-dataadapterfill-command-while-its-processing?forum=csharpgeneral)):

```
private BackgroundWorker worker;
private DataTable table;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (worker != null)
  {
    worker.CancelAsync();
  }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
  this.worker = new BackgroundWorker();
  worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
  worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

  worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
  worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

  worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show(this.table.Rows.Count.ToString());
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  this.table = new DataTable();

  using (SqlConnection connection= new SqlConnection())
  using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table", connection))
  {
    table.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(table_RowChanged); 
    da.Fill(table);        
  }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
void table_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
  if (worker.CancellationPending)
  {
    throw new ApplicationException("Canceled"); // throw a spanner in the works
  }
  Thread.Sleep(5); // Just slow things down for testing
}
```